# angular.element html didn't work

Tags: jquery, angularjs

This is my html file. Note Id can be changed

```
   <span id="use_l3_vpn_id" class="propertyValue ng-binding">false</span>
```

In my controller I have these code

```
 var element = angular.element(self.propertyId)[0];
  angular.element(element).html(property.value);
 // $(self.propertyId).text(property.value); // jshint ignore:line
```

It didn't work when I used angular.element but it worked with jquery
if I commented the first 2 lines of code and use the third line of code it worked $(self.propertyId).text(property.value);
Any idea why it didn't work with angular.element

Comment: None of this dom code should be in controller in the first place. Controllers run before templates are compiled. DOM manipulation should be done in directives. Or for inserting html use `ng-bind-html`

Comment: Why dont you try like this angular.element(self.property).text(property.value)

Comment: angular.element(self.property).text(property.value) is worked. Thanks but charlietfl has suggested to use ng-bind-html. Let me try that. Thanks to all